# SubString Text Selection

Tags: c#, substring

I'm using C#, and have the following string text value:

```
get directions from Sydney to Melbourne
```

And this is the code that I have at the moment to try and get the text that appears between *From* and *To*

```
String fromDestination = InputTextbox.Text;
if (fromDestination.Contains("from"))
{
   fromDestination = fromDestination.Substring(fromDestination.IndexOf("from") + 5, fromDestination.IndexOf("to") - 3);
}
```

That code removes the word "from" from the returned value, but I cannot work out how to get ride of the "to". The output at the moment is:
*sydney to Melb*

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you read [what substring does](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx)? First param is start index, second param is length, not end index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another possible route (lolpun)..

You can split via "from" and "to". Each part is created for you then:

```
var str = "get directions from Sydney to Melbourne";

var parts = str.Split(new string[] { "from", "to" }, StringSplitOptions.None); // split it up
var from = parts[1]; // index 1 is from
var to = parts[2];   // index 2 is to

Console.WriteLine(from); // "Sydney"
Console.WriteLine(to);   // "Melbourne"
```

Comment: I like this solution as it gets both "from" and "to" as string outputs.
One more question with this though, the output for "from" includes an additional space after it. Is there a way to get rid of that please?

Comment: Include it in your split strings.. so `" from "` and `" to "`.

Comment: Not my downvote, but I see a couple of potential problems. First the split method builds a string array and it is a expensive operation, but the most important one is the lacking of control if the resulting array contains the substrings or not. Of course if the OP has the absolute control on the input string then there is no problem at all

Comment: Mmm, true. Not sure it deserves a downvote _after_ being accepted though :(

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter to pass to the Substring method is the number of chars to extract from the instance string, not another position

```
String fromDestination = InputTextbox.Text;
int pos = fromDestination.IndexOf(" from ");
if(pos >= 0)
{
   int pos2 = fromDestination.IndexOf(" to ", pos);
   if(pos2 > -1)
   {
      int len = pos2 - (pos + 6);
      fromDestination = fromDestination.Substring(pos+6, len);

   }
}
```

Notice that I have changed the search strings adding a space before and after `from` and `to`. This is a precautional measure required to avoid false positives when a city name contains 'to' as part of its name or if there is another `from` embedded in the text before the actual starting `from`

Answer (score 0):

If the string is always the same I would suggest a simple string split.

`string fromDestination = InputTextbox.Text.Split(' ')[3];`

Answer (score 0):

```
Substring(startIndex, length)
```

for compute the length you should try to `fromDestination.Length - fromDestination.IndexOf(" to ")`

```
fromDestination.Substring(fromDestination.IndexOf(" from ") + 5, fromDestination.Length - fromDestination.IndexOf(" to "));
```

Comment: Let's hope none of the destinations have "to" in the name!

Comment: `get directions from ____ to ____` maybe the name is fixed!

Comment: My point is what happens with "get directions from Blahto to Melbourne"?

Comment: Yes. Personally I'd also check and make sure both of those indexes are found and that "to" comes after "from" before I try to start substringing.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use regular expressions:

```
String fromDestination = "get directions from Sydney to Melbourne";
var match = Regex.Match(fromDestination, @"(?<=from\s).*(?=\sto)");
if (match.Groups.Count > 0)
    fromDestination = match.Groups[0].Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the string "Sydney Melbourne":

```
string fromDestination = "get directions from Sydney to Melbourne";
string result = fromDestination.Substring(fromDestination.IndexOf("from") + 5).Replace("to", "");
```

By the look you probably would be better off replacing the textbox for 2 comboboxes,each with their items filled by a predefined list of available cities so the user cannot enter any typos for example and you just react to the selectedindex of the combobox...